# a zero morphism on t-structures

Tags: homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

Good morning to everyone, I am writing here because I need to understand better some topics about t-structures on triangulated categories.

Consider this statement: take a, b in $\mathbb{Z}$, $(\mathscr{C}^{\leq 0}, \mathscr{C}^{\geq 0})$ a t-structure on a triangulated category $(\mathscr{C}, [1], \partial)$ and $C$ an object of $\mathscr{C}$.

For any $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, $X$ in $Ob(\mathscr{C})$, I call

$$\Delta_{X}^{0} : \tau^{\leq 0}(X) \rightarrow^{T^{\leq 0}(X)} X \rightarrow^{T^{\geq 1}(X)} \tau^{\geq 1}(X) \rightarrow^{h_{X}^{0}} \tau^{\leq 0}(X)[1]$$

the distinguished triangle coming from the axioms of the t-structure.

Is the equality

$$T^{\geq a}(C) \circ T^{\leq b}(C) = 0$$

true if $b \lneq a$?

I tried to prove it, but I did not manage. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you reduce to the case $a = 1$, $b = 0$ in which case this is one of the axioms for a t-structure?

Comment: Did you check it using induction on a - b? By the definition of the Tn's built by the T0 and T1. (Sorry for my bad English) Anyway I thank @JHF , for the quick hint.

Comment: My thought was to use the shift equivalences to shift $b$ to $0$, and then observe that the truncation factors through $T^{\geq 1}$.  But I suppose the idea is not that different from yours.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this answer.

By the axioms

$\bullet$ $\mathscr{C}^{\leq -1} \subseteq \mathscr{C}^{\leq 0}$

$\bullet$ $\mathscr{C}^{\geq 1} \subseteq \mathscr{C}^{\geq 0}$

$\bullet$ $Hom_{\mathscr{C}}(\mathscr{C}^{\leq 0}, \mathscr{C}^{\geq 1}) \cong 0$

I can prove that

$$\hspace{-130pt} Hom_{\mathscr{C}}(\mathscr{C}^{\leq n}, \mathscr{C}^{\geq m}) \cong 0$$

for any $n$ and $m$ integers such that $n \lneq m$, using induction on $m - n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$.

By the relation $$\hspace{-90pt} T^{\geq a}(C) \circ T^{\leq b}(C) \in Hom_{\mathscr{C}}(\mathscr{C}^{\leq b}, \mathscr{C}^{\geq a}) \cong 0$$ I am done.

If there are some mistakes, please let me know.

Anyway, thanks for everyone who read this thread.